# R if statement about a web page

Tags: r

I know I can open a web page from R using  "shell.exec".
But I want to write a loop that opens the webpage only if the webpage 
maintains a condition, for a collection of websites.

It's a collection of websites that have "value=somenumber" in their address,
and I want R to open only those that "somenumber" actually have some data.
Numbers that don't have data don't return an error page, but just a page with no data.

The thing is, it's involving like html elements that I need to write in the condition...

is such thing possible?

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `stringr` library's `str_detect`

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf#page.7

Assuming you have a list of the urls.  I would just pass that list to the function and if it returns true then do your thing.

```
str_detect(urlList,"value=[:digit:]")
```

Comment: you can do this in base with `grepl`:  `grepl('value=[[:digit:]]+', urlList)`.  (FWIW, `str_detect` is a thin wrapper over `grepl`)

Comment: ya it is but readability is always important.  And when reading over the code str_detect makes a lot more sense then grepl.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that uses the more portable `browseURL` and `grep`:

```
x <- readLines(n=3)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840523/check-if-os-is-solaris
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817341/faster-i-j-matrix-cell-fill
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863710/correlating-word-proximity

sapply(grep("/238", x, value=TRUE), browseURL)
```